# Checking if a number is right sorted

Tags: list-manipulation, code-review, number-theory, number-representation, big-numbers

I have a number $n$ such that the digits of $n$ are strictly increasing to the left except for the first digit. So for example when $n=51369$ fits the bill because:

$$1<3<6<9\tag1$$

Is there a way to write Mathematica code that checks if the number $n$ satisfy this criterion?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
f1 = OrderedQ @* Rest @* IntegerDigits;

f1 /@ {51369, 51396}
```

> ```
> {True, False}
> ```

```
f2 = Apply[LessEqual @ ##2 &] @* IntegerDigits;

f2 /@ {51369, 51396}
```

> ```
> {True, False}
> ```

Answer (score 7):

```
f = AllTrue[Rest[Differences[IntegerDigits[#]]], Positive] &
```

Test:

```
f /@ {51369, 412345, 824699, 41395, 31832}
```

> True, True, False, False, False}

---

**EDIT** Visually,

```
alist = Range[1000];
blist = (Boole /@
     f /@ alist) /. {{} -> Black, 0 -> Red, 1 -> Darker@Green} // 
  Multicolumn
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A slight variation on the method given by @kglr

```
51369//IntegerDigits[#,10,IntegerLength[#]-1]&//OrderedQ
(* True *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `SequenceCount`

```
f = SequenceCount[Rest @ IntegerDigits[#], x_ /; LessEqual @@ x] == 1 &;

f /@ {51369, 51396}
```

{True, False}

Answer (score 2):

Using `Split`:

```
f = Length@Split[Rest@IntegerDigits[#], LessEqual] == 1 &;

f /@ {51369, 51396}

(*{True, False}*)
```